# SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'deleted_at' at row 22

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute this:

```
ALTER TABLE categories
ADD COLUMN country_id int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT categories_country_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES countries (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Countries table
[image]

Categories table
[image]

Comment: you need first to update the column so that there are no more values with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: change timestamp column type to datetime for deleted_at column

Comment: Why is that????

Comment: have you checked the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html